# How to switch OS's After installing Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, windows-10, bootloader, 17.10

I have two separate partitions on my drive, one for Lubuntu 17.10 (which was installed first) and then a partition for Windows 10 (currently fall creators update). I noticed that when Windows finished installing, grub would no longer pop up giving me an option to boot to Lubuntu. I tried to go to the Windows boot manager, but, unless I was doing it wrong, it doesn't show the "choose a different OS" button. Note that the Lubuntu installation is the first partition on the disk. How can I make it so that either grub or the Windows boot manager can show up to give me a choice in my operating system?

Comment: Due to you installing windows later it removed all traces of grub. Create and use a live grub-repair usb/dvd to re-install grub. Windows boot manager can not include Ubuntu.

Comment: as Rinzwind suggested, you need to repair grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair go for second option, it requires Internet connection.  this doesn't https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/294611